# My wallet is hacked... whenever sol or any token is sent it get drained instantly

Tags: wallet, transaction

my wallets was hacked like 11 months ago maybe seed was compromised.

Gn8crAJsHYNf1ELT8x7EeecbELGTGngyfjRKSeLMyQyF
643BzCV3TCvfb2aC6biZHQWH8oCMK4HbDuUUbmiJYNHi
ALo6aMj7MzRxPwecayWTuNiavGBkrJX8DdKJQMhG5jWS
ESsfzwjN5BnXud6MPdxhqpcqM8hbUwcsaqzMEstSULEo

here are the 4 wallets I used

is there any solution to stop the attack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wallet is hacked... whenever sol or any token is sent it get drained instantly](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9674/my-wallet-is-hacked-whenever-sol-or-any-token-is-sent-it-get-drained-instantl)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting from such a vague question. This is not a development or specifically Solana related question. I'm sorry your funds were lost. But this isn't really a place to discuss or get answers about it. In general. don't interact with malicious dApps or click on random links, especially from scam NFT drops.