# My wallet is hacked... whenever sol or any token is sent it get drained instantly

Tags: wallet, transaction

my wallets was hacked like 11 months ago maybe seed was compromised.

Gn8crAJsHYNf1ELT8x7EeecbELGTGngyfjRKSeLMyQyF
643BzCV3TCvfb2aC6biZHQWH8oCMK4HbDuUUbmiJYNHi
ALo6aMj7MzRxPwecayWTuNiavGBkrJX8DdKJQMhG5jWS
ESsfzwjN5BnXud6MPdxhqpcqM8hbUwcsaqzMEstSULEo

here are the 4 wallets I used

is there any solution to stop the attack?

Answer (score 1):

If someone has your seed phrase they will always be able to do whatever they want with the derived wallets.
The only solution is to transfer everything out as fast as possible and create a new wallet from a fresh seed phrase.

Comment: just to add to the comment. It's possible that you don't only have the seeds compromised, and have your system compromised, and even if you create new accounts with new seeds, it will not really matter. Stay safe.